# How to install RMySQL package

Tags: sql, r, rmysql

I need to install the RMySQL package but I cannot find it on the install package menu and even selecting different mirror it doesn't work... how can I do?

```
> install.packages("RMySQL")
Installing package(s) into ‘C:/Users/admin/Documents/R/win-library/2.15’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)

   package ‘RMySQL’ is available as a source package but not as a binary

Warning message:
package ‘RMySQL’ is not available (for R version 2.15.2)
```

Comment: What OS are you on? I'm assuming Windows?

Comment: Windows is my OS but I think I have a version (latest?) which dows not support the RMySQL package

Comment: @RomanLuštrik Good spot